# Why I can't change color of breadcrumb list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have breadcrumb and my problem is I can't change text color of breadcrumb lists. I changed font weight successfully, but color is problem.
I tried to write `color: white;` , but not working, down is code.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">

            <img src="img/Gallery/fb.png" alt=""> &nbsp
            <img src="img/Gallery/twitter.png" alt=""> &nbsp
            <img src="img/Gallery/youtube.png" alt=""> &nbsp
            <img src="img/Gallery/myspace.png" alt="">

            <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a class="active">Home</a></li>  &nbsp
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>  &nbsp
            <li> <a href="#">FAQ</a></li>   &nbsp
            <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ol>

            <p><small>Copyright <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span>  All Right Reserved | Testing Website </small></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col-xs-12 .breadcrumb{
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    color: white;
    font-family: TW Cen MT;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight: bold;

}
.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  content: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line then it will probably work fine, the `<a href="">` tag has some default html styling on it.

```
ol > li > a {color:white}
```

Comment: Thank you thats it, i will accept your answer.
can you tell me, how to write before ol i want to write .breadcrumb ifyou understand me

Comment: U mean `.breadcrumb li a {color:white}` that's also possible even better. It's the same as `<ol>` only if you target `.breadcrumb` you will only target that specific list of breadcrumbs in this case

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your css:

```
.breadcrumb li a    {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but too late, @Paul was a fast, and I will accept his answer. I accept you answer like useful
Thank you again